# How can I search a value in one column and search the same value in another ONLY if the first one does not exist?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to write a query to do the following, explained in pseudo-code:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE n
AND col2 LIKE x
OR col3 LIKE x ONLY IF x in col2 does not exist
```

**So what I want to do is to count every X value in col2, and only if it doesn't exist in col2, search and count the same value in col3.** I've been thinking about doing it maybe with NOT EXISTS and a subquery, but my SQL is rusty

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect that this does what you want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE n AND
      (col2 LIKE x OR col3 LIKE x)
```

Strictly speaking, though, you might want:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table
WHERE col1 LIKE n AND
      (col2 LIKE x OR col3 LIKE x AND col2 NOT LIKE x)
```